# How to deploy an Echo app with HTTPS in GKE?

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, https, google-kubernetes-engine

How to deploy an Echo app with HTTPS in GKE?

Using [Echo](https://echo.labstack.com/) framework developed a web app. Set `https://<DOMAIN>` feature with its [Auto TLS](https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/auto-tls).

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    env := os.Getenv("ENV")
    if env == "prod" {
        e.AutoTLSManager.HostPolicy = autocert.HostWhitelist("arealdomain.com")
        e.AutoTLSManager.Cache = autocert.DirCache("/var/www/cert")
        e.Pre(middleware.HTTPSWWWRedirect())
    }

    e.GET("/healthcheck", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, {"ok"})
    })

    switch env {
    case "prod":
        e.Logger.Fatal(e.StartAutoTLS(":8443"))
    case "dev":
        e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":9000"))
    default:
        e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":9000"))
    }
}
```

Deployed it in Kubernetes.

development.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapp
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: testapp
          image: gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/testapp
      ports:
      - containerPort: 9000
      - containerPort: 8443
      livenessProbe:
        initialDelaySeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 10
        exec:
          command:
            - "true"
      readinessProbe:
        initialDelaySeconds: 5
        periodSeconds: 20
        httpGet:
          path: /healthcheck
          port: 9000
```

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: testapp
```

ingress.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: testingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: testip // a real IP
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: testcertificate
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: testapp
    servicePort: 80
```

managedcertificate.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: testcertificate
spec:
  domains:
    - arealdomain.com  // a real domain
```

After deployed these resources, access domain `arealdomain.com`, got 502 error:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

From GCP's [network loadbalancer](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/loadBalancers), got one service is unhealthy.

[image]

Maybe firewall issue: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-http-lb-simple#firewall

Check kubernetes's deployment pod, found this error:

```
Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 400
```

Since want to deploy this web app can be used by https, so deployed it with 8443 port only. Use site like: https://arealdomain.com
But if do healthcheck, does GCP need other port? What's the best practice to do this deployment to GCP? Is it necessary to use Nginx to serve both 9000 and 8443 port inside app?

---

## Update

When change to use `80` port in Ingress, also deployed application on 9000 port, the pod can start but `neg` check seems can't pass.

```
  Events:
  Type    Reason                             Age    From                                                  Message
  ----    ------                             ----   ----                                                  -------
  Normal  LoadBalancerNegNotReady            115s   neg-readiness-reflector                               Waiting for pod to become healthy in at least one of the NEG(s): [k8s1-173zho00-default-testapp-80-l4cadn29]
  Normal  Scheduled                          115s   default-scheduler                                     Successfully assigned default/testapp-2c6f02f021-afjls to gke-<project_name>-default-pool-asfjo2c5-afjl
  Normal  Pulling                            114s   kubelet, gke-<project_name>-default-pool-asfdl0-asl3  Pulling image "gcr.io/<project_name>/testapp"
  Normal  Pulled                             109s   kubelet, gke-<project_name>-default-pool-asfdl0-asl3  Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/<project_name>/testapp"
  Normal  Created                            109s   kubelet, gke-<project_name>-default-pool-asfdl0-asl3  Created container testapp
  Normal  Started                            109s   kubelet, gke-<project_name>-default-pool-asfdl0-asl3  Started container testapp
  Normal  LoadBalancerNegWithoutHealthCheck  94s    neg-readiness-reflector                               Pod is in NEG "Key{\"k8s1-173zho00-default-testapp-80-l4cadn29\", zone: \"southamerica-east1-c\"}". NEG is not attached to any BackendService with health checking. Marking condition "cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready" to True.
```

I found this [article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/container-native-load-balancing#pod_readiness), how to set `cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready` to `True`?

The GCP network's `Load balancer details` still showing unhealthy.

[image]

From `Health Check` details, the path didn't been set to `/healthcheck` but `/`. Where is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a NodePort service instead of a ClusterIP one? You're using an ingress already, so it's unnecessary to expose a K8s node port like that

Comment: @PabloFlores I did it by this guide: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#setting_up_the_managed_certificate

Comment: try setting the scheme (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#http-probes) property on the readiness probe to https, since your healthcheck is expecting an https connection as well

Comment: Also, it may not be necessary for you to use the AutoTLS feature in your app, as the GKE ingress will take care of TLS termination, so you just need to deploy your service as a normal http one and GCE will take care of only allowing https connections to it

Comment: @PabloFlores Thank you. I added `scheme: HTTPS` to readinessProbe, this time the pod's event showed `Readiness probe failed: Get https://10.0.0.253:8443/api/healthcheck: remote error: tls: internal error`. If remove `AutoTLS` from application, how to set k8s service? Now I'm using both `http` and `https`. Is it enough if I use `http 80 targetPort to 9000`? Current running 2 services, so running 2 pods for different ports.

Comment: Yes, it would be enough to target the service to port 9000. It's common to use port 8080 to listen to http traffic in containers to be clear on what protocol you are listening and to avoid the need of a privileged user (because listening on port 80 requires more privileges). Also update the ingress to send traffic to port 80 of the service. Additionally, you should try changing the service to a ClusterIP one

Comment: @PabloFlores Thank you again. I updated the question with an `Update` mark at the bottom. I tried reuse 80 port in ingress. Removed `https` protocal from service. Redeployed application on 9000(sure I can change to use 8080). But the GCP network checking still can't pass. Also I tried to use `ClusterIP` in service, but got `The Service "testapp" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Forbidden: may not be used when 'type' is 'ClusterIP'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just starting with GKE I recommend you to just create the service and deployment and use the UI to create the ingress and the managed certs

I created and deploy a sample application:

Code in main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // change this handlers for echo handlers
    http.HandleFunc("/", http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        rw.Write([]byte("Hello World..."))
    }))
    http.HandleFunc("/health", http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    }))
    log.Panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
RUN apk add --no-cache git
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN go build -o bin main.go

#final stage
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /go/src/app/bin /app
ENTRYPOINT ./app
EXPOSE 8080
```

k8s-artifacts.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testapp
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: testapp
          image: gcr.io/<ACCOUNT>/test  
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            exec:
              command:
                - "true"
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 20
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: testapp
---
apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "lb-2"
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: "testapp"
    servicePort: 80
```

With that in place, you will have at least an http ingress which you can access through the internet. After that, and when you have validated that your service is up and running, you can edit the front-end of the load balancer to add the https rules and your managed cert

**Update**

After verifying that the lb is up and running
[image: lb veryfication]
[image: access web site]

To edit the load balancer go to the ingress details[image: kubernetes engine services and ingress]

At the bottom of the page there are links to the load balancers managed by GCE [image: managed load balancers]

Select the load balancer and edit it [image: edit load balancer]

Go to front end configuration and configure a new front end and port for https
[image]

**Update 2**

You can also create directly the new ingress with the managed cert. For example: First, create the managed cert

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: test-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - test-domain.com
```

After that, just create a new ingress in the services and ingresses section of GKE
[image: create ingress]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The current problem is GKE maybe need health check for TLS application with its ingress feature. If use this way to deploy the app, how to set `ingress and the managed certs` from UI?

Comment: @warmwinter Updated the answer with instructions to update the ingress

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer! It resolved my problem now.